# Parsing xml containing character reference

Tags: xml, sax

The XML im trying to parse contains a control character 0x2 inside CDATA. I tried to replace it with character reference which led to CDATA looking like:

```
CDATA section----charcter reference----CDATA section
```

Now if i try to parse it i get an error message saying:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

The original xml looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-16"?><CELL><![CDATA[ABCD&#2;EFGH]]></CELL>
```

I modified it to:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-16"?><CELL><![CDATA[ABCD]]>&#2;<![CDATA[EFGH]]></CELL>
```

Comment: Post the actual XML you are asking about by editing your question. when you do this, select the XML and press the the 1010 button above the text entry area.

Answer (score 0):

Entity definitions are not resolved in CDATA sections, that is why your original example does not work. That the modified example does not work seems to be a SAX parser error in my opinion. Maybe the SAX parser does not allow an invisible byte order mark (BOM) before the XML prolog that starts with <?, but the SAX parser should.

To help the SAX parser the following workaround would eventually do. Namely consuming the BOM before you feed the parser. You could use a markable stream for this purpose, i.e. marking the stream, reading the BOM, reseting the stream to its mark if there was no BOM. I didn't try, its just a guess.

BTW: Your question would be perceived better if you would fix the typo in the intro: Write "character reference" instead of "charcter reference". I first thought that the missing a is related to your question.